# Use SQL to replace some different words in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new bird to SQL/MySQL and I am practicing SQL and database. I used MS Server Studio and typed:
"Select DocumentLevel,Title,Owner From Production.Document"，
and it showed like the picture under:
[image]
[Table 1, the owner column are showed as numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nm5y.png)

And I want to replace all the number into words in Owner column. Number 217 is Abby, number 219 is Billy, number 220 is Cindy. After the number are replaced, I wish the table would look like this:
[image]
[Table 1, but the owner column are showed as names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G26fI.png).

I use SQL like this:

```
Select REPLACE(Owner,'217','Abby') From Production.Document
```

but it only showed a column with no title and only one number 217 was replaced.

Could you help me to use SQL to get the table like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G26fI.png)?

Comment: `join` your `document` table with your table of `users`

Comment: *I used MS Server Studio* Are you sure that you use definitely MySQL and not MS SQL aka SQL Server?

Comment: The software I used is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018. I guessed I misunderstood SQL and MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is most likely an identity from another table.
So use it to get the data from the other table.

Let's assume that other table is Production.Persons
And it has the columns : ID, Name
Where ID is the primary key of Production.Persons

Then joining would work

```
Select DocumentLevel, Doc.Title, Owner.Name
From Production.Document As Doc
Left Join Production.Persons As Owner On Owner.ID = Doc.Owner
```

But if you're stuck without a table, and the teacher doesn't allow one.

Then you could use a `CASE` or `CASE WHEN` for the logic.

```
Select DocumentLevel, Title
, Case Owner
  When 217 Then 'Abby'
  When 219 Then 'Billy'
  When 220 Then 'Cindy' 
  End As Owner
From Production.Document
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, this my homework, and the teacher gave me the names to replace the number in Owner; so there is no table like you say (which had ID, Name). The teacher also asked me not create new table, so I got stuck.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll add an extra.

Comment: Thank you! I will find the SQL Case on Web, Thank you very much!

Comment: There's 2 forms. One to decode a value `CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END` or with seperate conditions `CASE WHEN x <= 3 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END`